# Transformation Diagrams for Ceramics

Tags: material-science, phase-transition

So, in the field of metallurgy, there are a few varieties of phase diagram that are used to predict the post-processing characteristics of alloys. These include *Time-Temperature Transformation* diagrams and *Continuous Cooling* diagrams. Currently, I've found myself working with metal oxides, and I'm trying to find what the equivalents are in this field.

It looks like so-call *Oxidation Curves* are a commonly used tool, but this doesn't give me any information on the microstructure or properties I can expect out of bulk materials. Are there such references?